# Accessing client side WebSQL database

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks, web-sql

Does anyone know of any tools, to access and query a WebSQL database on a BlackBerry device or simulator?

I have two problems, how can a simulator's local file system dmp file be opened and viewed?  (Or a real device's internal file store for that matter.)

Then, once you can get access to the file system, what tools can open the database that's inside it?

For iOS development, I have been downloading the sandbox, opening the package, and then using MesaSQLite to access the DB.  I'm trying to do something similar for BB, is it possible?

Comment: i think BB10 has IndexedDB but not WebSQL.

Comment: Luckily I'm only trying to support BB7 and BB7.1 at the moment! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any that come after me...

After extensive research, I've found no way to do this, and I'm pretty certain you can't do it.

However, at `bbwp` compile time adding `-d` to the command line enables the Web Inspector in the application, so you can use a browser session navigate to the database and look at the data, as well as navigate through the file system if you need to.

Further, if you add `/fs-sdcard /fs-sdcard-root="c:\whatevs-you-want-here"` to your command line for the simulator you can externalise the SD card file system, unfortunately there is no way to do the same for the device's internal file system.